# Add leading zero's to value of integer field in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper reports where I need to add leading zero's to the value of my field which is integer. ex (1 to 0001).

I want it that the value to be displayed will be four characters. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1.Right click the **textfield** => **field pattern** => **custom format** selection

2.Type number of 0's you desire format

```
***0000***

1 => 0001
25 => 0025
```